# modify existing class of google map

Tags: reactjs

I am completely beginner for React. I already passed some time on this but I don't know if I can edit a class that I have imported. Is it possible to modify the default behavior of JSX components which are for example Google Map component ( and  ?

For example :

```
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper,Polyline,Polygon } from 'google-maps-react';

export class Map extends Component {
 //add properties and methods and keep the old ones
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What would you like to modify in the Map component from the react library 'google-maps-react'? It is better if you can provide your use case.

Comment: I would like to add a click event on each polygon. For the moment, here's my code :
export class MapContainer extends Component {
...
render(){...return(<Map/><Polygon/><Polygon/>)}
I could add the onclick event directly in this class but I would find it cleaner to do it directly in the right class. I am learning also React by myself and I want to know it is possible to do so, thanks Pagemag

Comment: So you will have multiple <Polygon/> object in your code and you want each to have onClick. Indeed onClick is one of the events supported by the <Polygon/> of the google-maps-react library and you can use this parameter to handle on click event for each polygon. May I know what you mean by putting onclick directly in the right class?

Comment: I could add the function on polygon inside the map container class like this :
class MapContainer extends Component {
onPolygonClick{..}
 render(){
<Polygon
 onClick={(polyProps, poly,e) => eval(this.onPolygonClick(polyProps, poly,e ))}></Polygon>);
but I thought that the function which triggers on a custom jsx elements must be written inside the class of this jsx elements, Am I wrong ? I would find it more logical anyway